# How can I deal with carriage returns when going from NSString to PHP to MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, nsstring, carriage-return

I have a UITextView in my iPad app.  When the user inputs data to this view, I want to write it to a mysql database, using a PHP site I created.  I need to strip the carriage returns when I give it to the php site but is there some way to maintain the returns?

Comment: You need to strip them, but you want to keep them? A bit unclear to me.

Comment: I needed to get rid of the returns to navigate to the php site because the '\n' dont seem to work in a URL - so I replaced all '\n' with some arbitrary, unlikely string. Then in my PHP site, I replaced the arbitrary string with '\n' to put it into the mysql database.  Seems to work - Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a intermediate variable :

```
$stringWithoutCRLF = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ' ', $stringWithCRLF);
```

Here it replaces CRLF by space.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put so much data in your url? Keep in mind that there's a limitation to url length - you'd better use POST.

But anyway: you need to url-encode the data. Google says this'll work:

```
SString* escapedUrlString =
[unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                    NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This'll make it safe both for get and post requests.